# Python - Is it possible to run different proxies (auth) for each multithread?

Tags: python, multithreading, proxy

So I am wondering if its possible to run from a file (with proxies) and add it up to each profiles `Json` for every thread I am doing. In that case if I do have etc 5 profiles then right now every profile will get a each thread: ETC

```
def main():

    log("Loaded # of profiles: " + Fore.CYAN + str(configLen) + Fore.RESET)
    mylocale = config['event']['locale']
    locale = 'en_%s' % mylocale
    threads = []
    for i in range(configLen):
        t = threading.Thread(target=start, args=(str(i),locale,))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()
```

However I tried to add up:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=start, args=(str(i),locale,), proxies=proxies)
```

but then I realized I need to do something like

```
proxies = config['test']['profile_' + str(thread)]['proxy']

proxies = {
    'https': 'https://' + proxies
}
```

to actually be able to give the proxies to work but I'm not sure if that is possible. What suggestions do you guys have and maybe is this even possible to do?

**EDIT**

```
proxies = {'http': "http://username:password@IP:PORT", 
           'https': "http://username:password@IP:PORT", 
}

threads = []
for i in range(configLen):
    t = threading.Thread(target=start, args=(str(i),locale,), proxies=proxies)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

I have done like this but then it gives me a error saying :

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxies'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have separate method to determine proxy. That way each of your threads can call that method, with all params passed - to determine proxy.

### EDIT

You can pass the proxy, as a parameter and have it inside your start callable. Let's have proxy as you wrote:

```
proxies = {'http': 'proxy1', 'https': 'proxy2', 'local': 'proxy3'}
```

You can have:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=start, args=(str(i),locale,proxies['https']))
```

So your `start`:

```
def start(idx, locale, proxy):
    # ...
    print proxy
    # ...
```

should work.

Comment: Could you please show me a example? I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: Dzienkuje bardzo Michal! However. I just made a edit. Apprently I have a proxy that I got from a friend that is the same so instead of doing it for all profiles I was thinking to actually just implement that proxy directly to what I just edited. Is there any soulution out from the EDIT i have done?

Comment: Hi again Michal! I quite don't understand why it needs to be that complicated. Wouldn't it work if I just have the proxies = { ...... } and then just call t = threading.Thread(target=start, args=(str(i),locale,), proxies=proxies) ? Because basically what I just want to do is to add that proxy (that is in edit) to every single thread basically and that's it? No?

Comment: If your proxy is static, then you can calc it upfront, and pass. Problem is that it must be passed inside `args`, and taken as additional parameter. If that sounds reasonable, I'll update my version.

Comment: Yes, The proxy will be same all the time which means static for all so yes. It would be really nice if you could update out from my Edit i did :) would be the best sunday!

Comment: Oh alright, So what I can see from the edit you did. Basically I could then just do proxies = { 'https': 'username:password@ip:port' }

Comment: and then do the t = threading.Thread(target=start, args=(str(i),locale,proxies['https'])) without needing to do the start?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread - target is callable to be executed inside the thread - in your case that is named `start`. `t.start()` is the way you start the thread, and let it executing callable `start` in your case. :)

Comment: Oh correct! Yeah. I have done right now: 
proxies = {'https': 'username:pass@ip:port'}
t = threading.Thread(target=start, args=(str(i),locale,proxies['https']))